# Dynamically selecting table column

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, dynamicquery

I'm using JAVA JPA in spring boot. The scenario is my table is having around 8 columns (suppose id, A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)
from these I want 5 column as result E,F,G,H **and only one from A,B,C,D which will be not fixed for every execution**.

I have written like this.

@Query("Select :dynamicColName ,E,F,G,H FROM TABLEname where id= :id ")
List findById(@Param("dynamicColName")String dynamicColName, @Param("id")String id );

It's not working.
Here query isn't refering value of :dynamicColName as column name here.

Suggestion are highly appreciated.

Dynamic column name injection in query

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to implement dynamic queries is to use the **Spring Data JPA Specification**

The result will be something like this, you can choose the parameter you want to query with it.

```
List<PostComment> comments = postCommentRepository.findAll(
    orderByCreatedOn(
        byPost(post)
            .and(byStatus(PostComment.Status.PENDING))
            .and(byReviewLike(reviewPattern))
            .and(byVotesGreaterThanEqual(minVotes))
    )
);
```

more information:
https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-data-jpa-specification/

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1 - Workaround: You can use EntityManager:

```
static final String QUERY = "SELECT (%s),E,F,G,H FROM TABLEname where id=:id";        

@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;

Query createQuery(String dynamicColName, String id) {
    String sql = String.format(QUERY, dynamicColName);
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, YourTableEntityName.class);
    query .setParameter("id", id);
    return query;
}

public List<YourTableEntityName> findById(String dynamicColName, String id) {
    Query q = createQuery(dynamicColName, id);
    return q.getResultList();   
}
```

### Option 2 - CASE block: add a condition inside the SELECT query part:

```
SELECT
 CASE 
    WHEN (t.id >= 1000) THEN colunm1 
    WHEN (e.id < 1000) THEN colunm2 
    ELSE colunm3 END,
 E,F,G,H
FROM TABLEname t
WHERE id=:id
```

The solution will looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN (t.id >= 1000) THEN dynamicColName1 WHEN (e.id < 1000) THEN dynamicColName2 ELSE dynamicColName3  END, E,F,G,H FROM TABLEname t WHERE id=:id ") 
List findById(@Param("id")String id );
```

[Reference Wikipedia article: New in JPA 2.0](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL_BNF#New_in_JPA_2.0)

### Option 3 - JPA Criteria API

```
EntityManager em = ... ; 
CriteriaBuilder queryBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery qdef = queryBuilder.createQuery();

if (someCondition1) {
    //select columnA
    qdef.select(customer.get(TableEntity_.columnA));
} else if (someCondition2) {
    //select columnB
    qdef.select(customer.get(TableEntity_.columnB));
}
// where condition with ID check.
```

[OpenJPA:  Chapter 11. JPA Criteria](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.2/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_criteria.html#:%7E:text=The%20select()%20method%20defines,qdef.)

[Bueldung: JPA Criteria Queries](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries)